# Altering Views Exposed Form Elements and their Associated Labels

Tags: views, theming, forms, 8

I have a series of Views Exposed Forms across a Drupal 8 website. My goal is to generate unique template suggestions so I can theme each individual input and their labels differently as needed.

Here is my current approach. Placed into theme.theme.   I've hit a brick wall.

```
function HOOK_form_views_exposed_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['#attributes']['twig-suggestion'] = $form['#id'];
}

function HOOK_theme_suggestions_input_alter(&$suggestions, array $variables) {
    $element = $variables['element'];

    if (isset($element['#attributes']['twig-suggestion'])) {
      $suggestions[] = 'input__' . $element['#type'] . '__' . $element['#attributes']['twig-suggestion'];
    }
}

function HOOK_theme_suggestions_form_element_label_alter(&$suggestions, &$variables, $hook) {
    $element = $variables['element'];

    if (isset($element['#attributes']['twig-suggestion'])) {
      $suggestions[] = 'label__' . $element['#attributes']['twig-suggestion'];
    }
}
```

All input and label [#attributes] are null via Kint.
Here are the URLs I have referenced for background:

1) http://kevinquillen.com/drupal/2017/01/28/adding-twig-template-suggestions-for-form-elements

2) https://www.chapterthree.com/blog/how-to-create-custom-theme-suggestions-drupal-8

3) https://yellowpencil.com/blog/getting-granular-with-drupal-eight-forms/

Answer (score 0):

1. Should add `#attributes` to your element form so the form alter should be like:

```
function HOOK_form_views_exposed_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['name_of_element']['#attributes']['twig-suggestion'] = $form['#id'];
}
```

2. `HOOK_theme_suggestions_input_alter` will works only with input elements `textfield`.

Comment: You are so welcome, i'm glad that helped :)

Answer (score -1):

```
/*
*  hook_form_views_exposed_form_alter
*/
function THEMENAME_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-global-search-default'){
    $form['#attributes']['class'][] = 'row popup-form';  //add form class
    $form['combine']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'search_input';  //add class to input
    $form['combine']['#attributes']['placeholder'][] = t('Search...');
    $form['combine']['#theme_wrappers'] =  [];  //remove the extra stuff
    $form['actions']['submit']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'search_icon button';  //add class to button
  }
}
```